# replace existing nested folder in svn repository

Tags: svn

I have following folder structure :

```
-framework ( nested folder)
-app
```

I have to commit whole framework folder in svn using Eclipse/ command line.
I don't have idea what files are changed in framework and it is about 3 MB in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN works always on the whole directory including subdirectories and commits all changed files.

Have you tried to just execute `svn commit framework`?